# How can I stream logs from Cloudwatch to Kibana using Elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-cloudwatch, elk

My goal is to be able to visualize cloudwatch logs from AWS on a Kibana dashboard using the ELK stack but I am a little bit lost and don't know where to start. The docs were not very useful :(

Does anyone have any helpful resources to guide me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance!

Reading the elastic docs I always end up crashing into instructions to host on elastic cloud, but I am lookin for a free solution.

Comment: Kibana probably has built in support for CloudWatch APIs support through AWS keys I guess. You can create limited IAM role for this and start using w/ elk.

Answer (score 0):

AWS provides a [reference architecture for central logging](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/centralized-logging/) which sounds like a good match for your use case. This includes an [implementation guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/centralized-logging-on-aws/welcome.html) which you may find useful.

I know you said the documentation wasn't very helpful, so apologies if you've already seen this and didn't find it useful.